# Give Jinja2 variables from configParser

Tags: python, jinja2

So I have a working Jinja2 script that creates my templates, but since I will be using it multiple times, I wanted to create a config file which will make editing information for the template easier.

The working setup was this:

```py
service_name = "hostname01"
ports = (22, 443, 8080)
```

From my understanding, Jinja has to receive the `ports` list in parentheses but my config parser doesn't do that.

My config file:

```
[Service-Name]
Service_Name = hostname01

[Ports]
Ports = [22, 443, 8080]
```

My almost full script:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import configparser

#Choose templates location and load to env variable
loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=loader)

#Decalre config parser variables and the name of the config file
configParser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
configFilePath = (r'endpoint.cfg')
configParser.read(configFilePath)

#Declaring variables from cfg file
service_name = configParser.get('Service-Name', 'Service_Name')
ports = configParser.get('Ports', 'Ports')

#load the template to a variable
endpoint_service_template = env.get_template('endpointservice-template.yaml')

# This works but I don't want to hardcode information here
# service_name = "hostname1"
# ports = (22, 443, 8080)

#Render templates
endpoint_service_result = endpoint_service_template.render({'service_name':service_name, 'ports':ports})
```

I tried changing the square brackets in the cfg file to parentheses but didn't work. It seems like Jinja interprets that list as a string and outputs each number or letter inside of my template in both cases.

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the ports in a comma separated list and then convert them to a tuple in your code.
Please see below:

Config file:

```
[Ports]
Ports = 22, 443, 8080
```

Conversion in code:

```
ports = configParser.get('Ports', 'Ports')
ports = tuple([int(port.strip()) for port in ports.split(',')])
print(ports)
print(type(ports))
```

which gives me

```
(22, 443, 8080)
<class 'tuple'>
```